# Create list of test dynamically

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, dunit, dunitx

i use DUnitX in Delphi but i got stuck.
How can i create list of tests dynamically?

e.g. 
i have list of sql and need to test them all like

```
for i:= 0 to List.Count do
  begin
    AddTest(List[i].SQL, List[i].Info, List[i].MaxTime);
  end;
```

for one method this is simple

```
[Test]
procedure TestSingleSQL;
```

implementation

```
procedure TestSingleSQL;
Var tick: Cardinal;
begin
  tic:= GetTickCount;
  Connection.Execute(SQL);
  Assert.IsTrue(Abs(GetTickCount-Tick)<MaxTime);
end
```

But if i need list of tests then attribute is inadequate.
**RepeatTest** attribute is also inadequate,
because if one test failed inside 
then whole test is stopped, but i need to run all sql

any advice

**EDIT1**

in DUnit (Without X) this was possible like this

```
function CreateDBTests: ITestSuite;
Var i: Integer;
  baza: String;
  TS_Connected, TS_SumyZlecFakt, TS_WPLATY, TS_KONTRAHENT: ITestSuite;
begin
  Result:= TTestSuite.Create('Lista baz');

  TS_Connected:= TTestSuite.Create('Połączenia');
  TS_SumyZlecFakt:= TTestSuite.Create('SyumyZlecFakt');
  TS_WPLATY:= TTestSuite.Create('Wpłaty');
  TS_KONTRAHENT:= TTestSuite.Create('Kontrahent');
  for i:= 0 to ListaBaz.Count-1 do
    begin
      baza:= ListaBaz[i];

      TS_Connected.AddTest(TTestConnected.CreateDBListTest(baza));
      TS_SumyZlecFakt.AddTest(TestSumyZlecFakt.CreateDBListTest(baza));
      TS_WPLATY.AddTest(TestWplaty.CreateDBListTest(baza));
      TS_KONTRAHENT.AddTest(TestKontrahent.CreateDBListTest(baza));
    end;

  Result.AddSuite(TS_Connected);
  Result.AddSuite(TS_SumyZlecFakt);
  Result.AddSuite(TS_WPLATY);
  Result.AddSuite(TS_KONTRAHENT);
end;
```

what is equivalent in DUnitX?

Comment: Maybe this is not supported by DUnitX, because it is a framework for an **Unit Test** and you want to have an **Integration Test** :o)

Comment: @SirRufo DUnitX is not limited to unit tests. It's simply a mechanism for managing and running automated test cases. It can be used for far more than just unit tests.

Comment: I have to agree with Livius here: Creating individual test cases with different parameters for the same method to test was near to trivial with the TestSuite approach of DUnit. Up to now I was not able to achieve the same simple approach for DUnitX. That's why I am also interested in a solution here. To give another real world example: I have a class that calculates the German income tax for a given set of parameters. The official program description contains a table with several reference values for different parameter sets. The test suite creates one test case for each parameter set.

Comment: If it is easy with DUnit then why don't you stick with it?

Comment: If you edit your question don't remove earlier edits: `[Test]`

Comment: @Stefan Glienke Yes, you have right. I supposed that DUnitX is successor of DUnit - but this is totally different framework. I see that better i will invest time to extend functionality of DUnit to support attributes for simple tests.

Comment: @Livius Save your time and use what I already did ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/9006662/587106

Comment: You have my vote :) This is exactly what i plan make tomorrow - but it exist now, i really save time, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/postid/697/introducing-dunitx) description DunitX is attribute-driven. It is not meant to be a drop-in replacement (or an extension) for DUnit. So I guess it does not support dynamic test case creation.

p.s. I am the author of an open source component test [framework](https://github.com/michaelJustin/openctf) which is based on DUnit and makes heavy use of dynamic test generation.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in some way by declaring test cases in a JSON file and hooking into the DUnitX plugin system :

https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX/issues/211#issuecomment-411082097

Comment: looks interesting i will test this. But why it use superobject?

Comment: I'm still using Delphi XE2 and I use extensively SuperObject for ages. I'm sure there are plenty other solutions to this problem of passing values to the test method.