# dataProvider in DUnit Delphi?

Tags: unit-testing, delphi

How to provide data for Unit Tests in Delphi DUnit) ? For example, in PHP, you can do something like this:

```
  public function URLProvider() {
    return [
      ["https://helloacm.com"],
      ["https://codingforspeed.com"]
    ];
  }

  /**
   * @dataProvider URLProvider
   */  
  public function test_url($url) {
    $data = file_get_contents("$this->API?url=$url");
    $result = json_decode($data, true);
    $this->assertEquals(true, $result['result']);
    $this->assertEquals(200, $result['code']);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DUnit every single test case has to be a `procedure` without parameters. So there can't exist a mechanism for injecting arguments via [custom attributes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declaring_Custom_Attributes) to test methods like you are doing it PHPUnit.

You should take a look at [DUnitX](https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX) instead where you can define tests like this:

```
[TestCase('https://helloacm.com')]
[TestCase('https://codingforspeed.com']
procedure TestUrl(const Url: String);
```

Comment: Not entirely correct - DUnit can have parameterized test methods as I have shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9006662/587106)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that. That's why I'm here answeing on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3):

With Spring4D DUnit extensions you can write something like that (look into the `release/1.2` branch in the `Tests\Source` folder for the unit `Spring.Testing`).

```
program Tests;

uses
  Spring.Testing,
  TestInsight.DUnit;

type
  TUrlTests = class(TTestCase)
  public
    class function UrlProvider: TArray<string>; static;
  published
    [TestCaseSource('UrlProvider')]
    procedure TestUrl(const url: string);
  end;

{ TUrlTests }

procedure TUrlTests.TestUrl(const url: string);
begin
  // do whatever
end;

class function TUrlTests.UrlProvider: TArray<string>;
begin
  Result := ['https://helloacm.com', 'https://codingforspeed.com'];
end;

begin
  TUrlTests.Register;
  RunRegisteredTests;
end.
```

You can either pass the name to the method within the same Testcase class or specify another class - the method itself must be a public static class function. The extension then will create different test cases for each parameter being passed. You can check the Unittests of Spring4D for other use cases.